# Run google scripts from android device

Tags: android, google-apps-script

I have a google script that fetches some data from an excel sheet. The data is returned as JSON. The excel sheet is shared between a set of users. I can run the script from browser, if I am logged in as google user. How can I execute the script from an android application. How do I execute the script as the user (user at the keyboard)?

Answer (score 1):

I have some samples of a simple Android app calling an Content Service URL. You have to publish your apps to be accessible publicly.

https://github.com/entaq/GoogleAppsScript/tree/master/Android

Comment: Content service is key. Regarding running it as the user, that's an option when you publish it but it requires that users manually enter once from a browser and approve permissions. You then make the call withCredentials from a urlfetch thou im not sure if thats possible outside of webview.

Comment: Arun I have published the app and its working fine in browser. The only problem is it does not work outside browser. It needs google authentication to work. So is there any way in which I can supply client secret or app Id in HTTP header or something??

Comment: Not at this point, you need to publish your app anonymously for now.

Answer (score 0):

By "excel sheet" you mean **Google Sheets**, right?

From what you explained, it seems that you script is published as a web-app. To access it on android, just open the browser and hit the app url. Running as the developer or the user is just an option when you're deploying the script as a web-app.

Comment: Ya, that's right. But I am using the script only as a content service. The data is used in an android app. Need to call the script from android app. Any possibilities ?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to call a `ContentService` script running as the user. If you ever manage to do this, please remember to provide an answer to this question so we can all benefit from it.